# Draw Borders around an image using swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, border, draw

How would I draw an inner and outer circle to highlight the color wheel in an image? Basically I have an image and I want to draw 2 black circles within the image. Thanks!

Comment: This image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/BYR_color_wheel.svg

Comment: could you post your code?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the image into a UIView and draw programmatically two circles using CoreGraphics, in the drawRect method of the UIView.